# socketChannel throws IOException with Permission Denied

Tags: java, network-programming, nio

A code that worked me for a while now on various platforms started to suddenly to fail, there were changed in the code but not in an area that related to this place.

The line of code that throws the exceptions is:

```
(SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel()).finishConnect()
```

And it throws:

> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: no further information

what may be the issue?

Some log lines that might show more info, it is a test code:

> 2016-12-04 22:50:10,585 [main] DEBUG Socket - Socket-Client-1-1
>   register to connect to address: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
>   2016-12-04 22:50:10,585 [main] DEBUG SocketSelector - Registering keys:
>   OP_CONNECT  (for Socket-Client-1-1)
>   2016-12-04 22:50:10,595 [main] DEBUG SocketSelector - Registered to: OP_CONNECT      > 2016-12-04 22:50:10,595 [NetworkThread] DEBUG SocketSelector -Got selected keys
>   for channel (java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending
>   remote=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080])

Comment: Have you called `connect()` on this channel? Have you previously called `finishConnect()` on it? If so, did it return true?

Comment: Yes I called connect() and it was successful. finishConnect() throw this Exception from the very first time.

Comment: Why are you connecting to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: later i changed it to local host and it didn't change anything

Comment: Please post the code that connects to 127.0.0.1, and the corresponding error and log entries, in your question. Everything to do with 0.0.0.0 is invalid and irrelevant and should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to connect to 0.0.0.0, which is not a valid TCP target address. This causes EPERM for the reasons described in *man connect*.

Use 127.0.0.1 or a proper IP address.